# Use variable to make-up property name

Tags: c#

In C# Asp.net, I'm trying to dynamically add a screenshot each time, and there's a limit of 6 screenshots - so I want to do a while loop for when `i` is less than 7, and use the `i` variable to access the properties of the model:

```
while (i < 7)
{
    var screenshot = new Screenshot()
    {
        ScreenshotId = addedScreenshot.Image(i),
        ScreenshotType = "Screenshot" + i,
        UserId = addedScreenshot.User.Id,
        IsVisible = true
     };
     _context.Screenshots.Add(screenshot);

     i++;
 }
```

This line: `addedScreenshot.Image(i)` is where I am trying to do this.

I've tried `addedScreenshot.Image[i]` and `Image(i)`, but none work. I just want it so it goes like:

```
addedScreenshot.Image1

addedScreenshot.Image2
```

etc

The error is that there's no property named 'Image', which is correct, but it should be concatenating the variable on to it.

If anybody could let me know where I'm going wrong, that'd be great.

Comment: What data type is the variable Screenshots?

Comment: The error is that there's no property named 'Image', which is correct, but it should be concatenating the variable on to it.

Comment: I agree with user1666620 above, however if you really do want this in the current format change the first line in the screenshot variable to ScreenshotId =  "addedScreenshot.Image" + i,

Comment: This doesn't provide enough information (except to tell you what you already know, that you can't do that.) This is about a property of `addedScreenShot`, but we don't know what that is. The question is really about that, so that's what we need to see.

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching this from the wrong direction. What happens if a user decides to add a third image? And then a fourth? Are you just going to add more and more properties to your model?

Your model should not have properties `Image1` and `Image2`. Instead it should have `List<Images> ImageList`. Then you find the image you want using the variable `i`.

Comment: How would I then use the Html.BeginForm to save the different images to that list and pass it to the model?

Comment: There are tutorials for that on the web. Start off by googling "MVC upload multiple images".